# Import python modules where . json error on Flask

Tags: python, apache, flask, pip, wsgi

When I installed python Flask on the Apache server and configured it via wsgi, an error occurred when importing python modules.

Python version 3.8.10

Flask version 2.3.2

```
ERROR:
   File "/var/www/gomed/data/www/doc.python.gomed.uz/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/init.py", line 1, in <module>
     from . import json as json
 ImportError: cannot import name json
```

I created a new configuration for `flask` in `apache` server.
this is my flask configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName doc.python.gomed.uz
    DocumentRoot /var/www/gomed/data/www/doc.python.gomed.uz/
    
    WSGIDaemonProcess app user=gomed group=gomed threads=5 python-home=/var/www/gomed/data/www/doc.python.gomed.uz/.venv python-path=/var/www/gomed/data/www/doc.python.gomed.uz/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/gomed/data/www/doc.python.gomed.uz/app.wsgi
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/flask-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/flask-access.log combined
    
    <Directory /var/www/gomed/data/www/doc.python.gomed.uz>
        WSGIProcessGroup app
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
</VirtualHost>
```

app.wsgi :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/gomed/data/www/doc.python.gomed.uz/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/')
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/gomed/data/www/doc.python.gomed.uz')
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/python3.8')
from main import app as application
```

I reinstalled pip requirements.

Comment: please also paste your app.wsgi
One thing to note is the scope of the package import. When you use `from .` its  in current directory of the process. You can just `import json`